# WCF writing directly to the response channel

Tags: wcf, performance

is there a way to write ( a string for example ) directly to the output stream, when implementing a regular WCF interface like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISearchInterface
{
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(Exception))]
    SearchResponse SearchXML(SearchRequest req);
}
```

I want to save de/serialization time and send the serialzed string directly( it HAS to be the same method, though, because when i haven't got the serialized cachestring, i want to normally "build" the serialized object by some SQL statements... )

Any ideas? Something like

```
Channel.Write(s);
```

??

Answer (score 1):

In one word: NO.

WCF is a **message-based** communication system - there is **NO** direct link between the server and your client at any time. All that goes between client and server are **serialized messages** - you can only exchange static data - there's no "object remoting" capability or anything like that in WCF. Heck - the messages between client and server could be sent by pigeons for all I know. And no, there's no way to send something back "directly over the channel" bypassing serialization - the response from the server must be serialized into a message and that message is sent back as a response to the client.

Comment: i guess you got me a littl wrong...  i want to bypass the process of serialization, that WCF does, because i already serialzed the data myself... see, the idea is to store serialzed data to a cache ( memcache ).. so, instead auf deserializing them and let them be serialized again by WCF, i want to directly put it through ( maybe a serializer overload is the method of choice here? )

Comment: I don't know of anything like that. You can do certain things on the server side to implement sort of a caching - but I've never heard of a way to circumvent the serialization process.